# Can Bioimpedance be used to prescribe essential oils and supplements?

Tags: biology

Bioimpedance (or [Bioelectrical impedance analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectrical_impedance_analysis)) has been used to measure body fat. However, there are products that claim to link the bioimpedance results to essential oils and supplements: this question was inspired by the claims of the [iTOVi scanner](https://www.itovi.com/).

For example, [the iTOVi scanner claims to send a variety of "frequencies" through your body which match essential oils](https://www.itovi.com/technology/). This results in a report indicating the "number of unresolved bio-points" which may be reduced / treated by specific essential oils (also in the report).

My question: is this indeed a reliable way to determine which supplements (eg [essential oils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_oil)) will benefit your health (if essential oils are indeed of benefit)?

iTOVi themselves [state](https://www.itovi.com/research/): *"iTOVi invites you to learn more about the scientific research backing the technology our products utilize."* And [they provide links to several research papers on this topic](https://www.itovi.com/research/).

<sub>Personally, I'm extremely skeptical. I ran an experiment in which I did three scans: twice with the same name and once with a different name. The two reports with the same name produced similar reports; the other report gave quite different results. However, [the site claims](https://www.itovi.com/technology/): *"If you run a repeat scan within a short period of time, the technology takes into account your previous scans and recommendations. This is very important. As the scanner gathers more information about your body’s responses, the more intuitive the results become."* But I don't want my skepticism to blind me if it a genuine product.</sub>